# TeXmacs conditionally independent symbol

Tags: texmacs

I want to type the conditionally independent symbol in TeXmacs, anyone knows how to do this? the symbol looks like two ⊥⊥ stick together.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the macro

```
<assign|indep|<macro|<math|<resize|<clipped|<rigid|\<bot\><move|\<bot\>|-0.6em|>>|0.18em||0.84em|>|0.3ex|||>>>>
```

and adapt it to your taste.

Comment: I recommend to avoid answers in the shape of rethoric questions. They tend to be misunderstood.

Comment: A better macro is this:
```
 <assign|indep|<macro|<math-relation|<superpose|\<bot\>|<move|\<bot\>|0.3ex|>>>>>
'''